# Revoking user permissions but maintaining groups in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I know that Users can have their own permissions and permissions inherited from their groups. I want to be able to remove a permission from a User that was granted to them by their group, but maintain their association to the group. Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Example: User Bob is in the Voter group. I want to revoke Bob's voting permission, but keep him in the Voter group.

Comment: I just was to ask the same question, I had the same issue. Are you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If this behavior is important for you, you could extend authentication backend to support checking a blacklist of user permissions, or assign Bob a higher-priority permission `'no voting'` and check it whenever `voting` permission is required...
But normally, splitting `Voter` group to `Voter` and another group such as `ForbiddenVoter`, and assigning Bod that group, could be more logically correct and easier to achieve.